# how to call a function inside function itself in python

Tags: python, function

do we have any way to assign a function inside function itself in python? I tried to call out a nth Fibonacci as below:

```
memo={0:0,1:1}
def fib(n):
    if n<=1:
        return n
    if memo[n] is None:
        fib(n)=fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
    return memo[n]

print(fib(5))
```

Comment: You're trying to implement function which return n-th element of fibonacci sequence and remember all calculated items for next searches?

Comment: You call a function inside itself the same way you would call it anywhere else, but `fib(n)=...` wouldn't be valid *anywhere*, inside or outside `fib`. Assigning to `fib(n)` is not what needs to happen here.

Comment: You're trying to implement function which return n-th element of fibonacci sequence and remember all calculated items for next searches? --> yes , correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two fixes

```
memo={0:0,1:1}
def fib(n):
    if n not in memo: # test
        memo[n] = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)   # <-- set memo
    return memo[n]

print(fib(5))
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. It's called recursion. However, you have some errors in your code...
Try -

```
memo={0:0,1:1}
def fib(n):
    if n not in memo:
        memo[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    return memo[n]
        
print(fib(5))
```

Comment: Actually, simple `list` will be enough for data container ([demo](https://tio.run/##VY3BDoIwEETvfMWEUxsLoXoz0U/wB0hjIBRsItum1oNfXy1ELXPa2X2z417hZukQ46BHjKbvGfFjgY/MiEmHLgTP0l6gnPVsS4GLJc1hHsuwskkJqhOCE9pGQKrvG8L5hLsm9kN4FrMeVxiC72jSbIuhghSgDN801Z1zmoZ/oK32CjtkXiq@ZL0OT0/ZhVRROG8oLGkmG84zv9bH@AY))